# when to use === operator check in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators, logical-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

As the title states; when should you use the `===` operator check when using JavaScript, and when not to.

Edit: more complete answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use). Thanks to Mark Byers for pointing it out.

_L

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is strict type equality operator. It not only checks whether two are equal in **value** but also of the same **type**.

Consider a situation when you compare numbers or strings:

```
if (4 === 4) // same value and type
{
  // true
}
```

but

```
if (4 == "4") // same value and different type but == used
{
  // true
}
```

and

```
if (4 === "4") // same value but different type
{
  // false
}
```

This applies to objects as well as arrays.

So in above cases, you have to make sensible choice whether to use `==` or `===`

It is good idea to use `===` when you are sure about the type as well

Comment: thanks for fast and thorough answer- will set as answer after the 15 minutes have passed

Answer (score 2):

When you wish to inhibit implied typecasts. For example:

```
3 == '3'
```

is `true`, whereas this is not:

```
3 === '3'
```

Douglas Crockford recommends always using strict comparison.

Comment: To be honest, I'm always a bit dubious when someone says "ALWAYS" do xxx. I can see situations where it is desiderable to compare a number to a string. Obviously you could manually cast the string to a number but if JS can do it for you why bother? :)

Comment: @nico, agree, there are cases where you simply don't need it, a common case is when you want to compare against `null` and `undefined` in one step, `if (foo == null)` does the job, or when  using the `typeof` operator, you also don't need it because it will *always* return a string... `if (typeof foo == "undefined")` is enough...

Answer (score 1):

You use it to check if a variable's containing value and type is same as the compared one.